TV episode with a higher-dimensional thing rotating off the side of a boat
The episode opens on a ship (boat) out on the ocean at night. Something strange happens and the crew goes above deck to find a thing hovering off the side, moving in strange ways and changing shape. It's about the size of a house and roughly spherical. Later in the episode, someone (an investigator?) suggests it's a higher-dimensional thing (maybe an alien craft) rotating in the 4th dimension.
My first guess was the pilot of Fringe, but no. It might be a different episode or another series entirely. It could even be a movie, but it definitely felt like Fringe: gritty, good CGI, menacing (for lack of a better word). I want to say it was released between 2008 and 2013.
I tried searching various combinations of "boat/ship/ocean" and "higher dimensional/4d/tesseract". I also looked at the lists here:

More than Three Dimensions - TV Tropes
Sci Fi movie suggestions exploring higher dimensional beings? - Reddit /r/movies


I was thinking of Threshold. From Wikipedia:

Threshold is an American science fiction drama television series that ran on CBS from September 16 to November 22, 2005. [...] The series focuses on a secret government project investigating the first contact with an extraterrestrial species.


One night, the crew of a U.S. naval vessel encounters a UFO. Many crew members subsequently die horribly, but some escape. After the ship is discovered with dead crew members and a videotape of the encounter, the Threshold protocol is activated.

I found some screencaps online:


The dialogue I was remembering was from the pilot:

Pegg: My God, look at the way it's folding in on itself. It's almost like we're dealing with some kind of higher-dimensional geometry, maybe a Kaluza-Klein manifold? [...] I think we're looking at a four-dimensional object in three-dimensional space. See how it keeps morphing? I think because we live in a three-dimensional world, we're only capable of seeing part of it.


Saw the title and immediately knew it was Threshold. I loved that show. Such a shame it didn't last

I was fascinated by the fact that in 2005 there were three new shows that had considerable similarities, and all were good, and all cancelled after one season.  They were: Threshold(CBS), Invasion(ABC), and Surface(NBC).  Common features: 1-word title, "theme" is a single sound that swells and fades, broad plot is some kind of takeover (by maybe aliens?) of people, converting them to something else.  I've wondered for all this time if maybe one treatment made the rounds and all three networks tried a version of it.  (Inb4: I know "Lost" did the swelling sound thing a couple of years earlier)
